# How can I see I've already cast a delete vote / How can I retract a delete vote?

Tags: support

So I've just [been told](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308896/why-network-manager-cant-detect-my-zte-usb-3g-modem/433935#comment998290_433935) someone edited their answer and I've come back and upvoted...

However, I noticed a delete flag and when pushing it, it shows me a dialog box with my remaining votes and I'm too scared to cast and (additional) vote...

So: did I cast a delete vote there and if yes, how do I retract it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to determine if it is your vote is to have the post actually deleted, then the users who voted will be listed in the [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/433935/revisions). Obviously that is a bit extreme for simple matters so we aren't going to do it ;)

There *are* cases where you can tell who cast some (or all) of the votes if the post went through the low quality post queue ([which this one did](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/477278)). Any reviews marked "delete" (vs "recommended deletion") are actual delete votes cast. Since there is only 1 vote and not enough time has passed since review to cause that vote to expire I'd say that delete vote isn't yours, but Eric's.

Answer (score 2):

You can't retract delete votes. It's a pending [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes). You can go through the delete votes you cast in [your profile page](https://askubuntu.com/users/344926/Fabby?tab=votes&sort=deletion) (no, I can't see anything there, only you can). I don't know of any other way.

Anyway, it seems the answer is now accepted, and we can't delete it. AT least, I see no option to delete it.

Comment: you can only vote to delete answers with a score of -1 or more.

Comment: More or less :)